# Bash script via .desktop save to variable external filename with fullpath

Tags: bash, files, scripting, xfce, desktop

ok i try to make the most resumed the points i want to do. Sorry for the repetions i don't know how make this question more objectively

The first i am making a script for launch "mupen64plus", is for use with "Xfce Desktop" with the file ""

The mupen64plus.desktop current content

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Mupen64Plus
GenericName=N64 Emulator
Comment=Nintendo 64 emulator and plugins for Linux, Mac OSX, FreeBSD, and Windows
Exec=xfce4-terminal --hold --execute /usr/bin/bash -c "/media/Compartido/Lignux/Videojuegos/Emulador/Nintendo/64/mupen64plus/portable/mupen64plus.geb" %F
Icon=/media/Compartido/Lignux/Videojuegos/Emulador/Nintendo/64/mupen64plus/portable/.mupen64plus.svg
MimeType=application/x-n64-rom;
Categories=Game;Emulator;
Keywords=Emulator;Nintendo64;Mupen64plus;
;NoDisplay=true
```

The idea on the bash script is the follow points

1. Get paths (script & absolute dir path)
2. Get external file with absolute path for example and save it on a variable called `ARCHIVO` - `/media/Inukaze1/N64/mupen64plus.v64` or `/media/Nicolas/Temporal/N64/ROMS/mupen64plus.v64`

   Because mupen64plus ever needs the absolute path of file to load it.
   for that reason because the path can be completely different i need store the absolute path on a variable (i prefer call the variable `ARCHIVO` for this case)

   Then the value of `ARCHIVO` just ever be one file, does not matter if i select multiples files (i don't want open accidentally multiple mupen64plus instances with different roms) like

   ```
    ARCHIVO='/media/samba/Inukaze/ROMS/Nintendo 64/Demos/Nintro 64'
    # or
    ARCHIVO='/mnt/cifs/Temp/N64Homebrews/Bike Race ’98'
   ```

   The reason for use `''` is for names like `Bike Race ’98`, that special character `’` can be a problem if i use `""`.
3. I already have some of script wrote, but is a lot because i ever put some things i need for specific title.
4. Start mupen64plus via .desktop file using "Open with" to load "N64 ROM" and start the rom correctly.

   You can find some homebrew & demos on site like nesworld and/or n64squid

Well i can put my script content on the post because appears the message "Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 41290."

My current mupen64plus.geb script content (my native lang is spanish because of that you can see a lot of spanish words)

View the script on this url -> https://controlc.com/f3d25176

Comment: And what's the question? What problem are you having? I think your script could be pasted here if you reduce the repetition and use more loops, remove all that extra whitespace (seriously those `rm ... ln` lines look nefarious, like you're hoping to hide the `ln` lines by having them lie beyond the viewport).

Comment: The question is how i can make the desktop file when use the bash script the bash script save the absolute path of file when i click "open with" "mupen64plus" and that open correctly the rom file i select. After i can test i can run any rom without problem i optimice my code. the ln and rms is because i need specific configurations for each title and for make mupen64plus run on any distro like a "portable"

Comment: Please don't add "solved" to the question

Answer (score 0):

i had write too new files, just to try to understand what is happend when i run the script via desktop file

The first new /home/inukaze/.local/share/applications/mupen64plus_test.desktop, the content is

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Mupen64Plus TEST
GenericName=N64 Emulator
Comment=Nintendo 64 emulator and plugins for Linux, Mac OSX, FreeBSD, and Windows
Exec=xfce4-terminal --hold --execute /usr/bin/bash -c "/media/Compartido/Lignux/Videojuegos/Emulador/Nintendo/64/mupen64plus/portable/mupen64plus_test.geb" %k
Icon=/media/Compartido/Lignux/Videojuegos/Emulador/Nintendo/64/mupen64plus/portable/.mupen64plus.svg
MimeType=application/x-n64-rom;
Categories=Game;Emulator;
Keywords=Emulator;Nintendo64;Mupen64plus;
;NoDisplay=true
```

The second is "/media/Compartido/Lignux/Videojuegos/Emulador/Nintendo/64/mupen64plus/portable/mupen64plus_test.geb" the content is :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#Determine in which directory i am located :
SCRIPT=$(readlink -f "$0")
SCRIPTPATH=$(dirname "$SCRIPT")
cd "$SCRIPTPATH"

#Get File Extension :
EXTENSION=$(echo "$1" | awk -F '.' '{print $NF}')

ARCH=$(uname -m)
case "$ARCH" in
    x86)    ARCH="x32"                      ;;
    i?86)   ARCH="x32"                      ;;
    amd64)  ARCH="x64"                      ;;
    x86_64) ARCH="x64"                      ;;
    * ) echo    "Your Architecture '$ARCH' -> Is not supported."    ;;
esac

ROMFILE="%k"    #I suppose i need redirect .desktop file %k to this bash variable called $ROMFILE
                            #To storage the absolute path of rom file. but is just an idea
                            
if [ "$ARCH" == "x64" ]
then
        export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="./.libs/64Bits":$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
        EJECUTABLE=".mupen64plus.x64"
fi

if [ "$ARCH" == "x32" ]
then
        export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="./.libs/32Bits":$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
        EJECUTABLE=".mupen64plus.x32"
fi

if [ -z "$1" ]
then
        echo ""
        echo -e "First Argument is Empty Variable\n"
        echo ""
else
        echo ""
        echo -e "First Argument is a File ; Check md5sum"
        MD5=$(md5sum "$1"| tr a-z A-Z | awk '{print $1}')
        echo ""
        echo 'Inside "if [ -z "$1"] else '
        echo "Reveal variable content : "
        echo '"$@"' = "'"$@"'"
        echo '"$*"' = "'"$*"'"
        echo '"$1"' = "'"$1"'"
        echo '"$2"' = "'"$2"'"
        echo '"%k"' = %k
        echo ""
        echo "Now First Try to run mupen64plus : without another script"
        ./.mupen64plus.x64 --corelib "./.libs/64Bits/libmupen64plus.so.2.0.0" --datadir "." --configdir "." "$@"
        echo "This work"
        echo "Now Second Try to run mupen64plus : via another script"
        bash -c "'"/media/Compartido/Lignux/Videojuegos/Emulador/Nintendo/64/mupen64plus/portable/mupen64plus.geb"'" < "$1"
        echo "This not work"
fi

echo -e ""
echo "i need when mupen64plus script run for any folder store the absolute path of rom i want to run"
echo "For example : "
echo -e ""
echo '"/media/Compartido/Lignux/Videojuegos/Emulador/Nintendo/64/mupen64plus/portable/mupen64plus.geb"' "'"/media/Nicolas/Temporal/ROMS/N64/Mupen64Plus.v64"'"
echo -e ""
echo "The first is absolute path my script"
echo "and the second is the absolute path of romfile"
echo "on another very diferent directory"
echo -e ""
echo "i don't have idea how redirect absolute path of romfile from .desktop file"
echo "to bash variable before the mupen64plus execute"

exit 0
```

i notice is i ran a "child" script via parent script or from desktop file, the variables from the parent or desktop file are not transfered to child script, i think this is the problem i should solve for make it work i need it.

if i use the follow commands on a terminal

```
cd /tmp
"/media/Compartido/Lignux/Videojuegos/Emulador/Nintendo/64/mupen64plus/portable/mupen64plus_test.geb" '/media/Nicolas/Temporal/ROMS/N64/Mupen64Plus.v64'
```

The output(s) are :

From Parent script :

```
First Argument is a File ; Check md5sum

Inside "if [ -z "$1"] else 
Reveal variable content : 
"$@" = '/media/Nicolas/Temporal/ROMS/N64/Mupen64Plus.v64'
"$*" = '/media/Nicolas/Temporal/ROMS/N64/Mupen64Plus.v64'
"$1" = '/media/Nicolas/Temporal/ROMS/N64/Mupen64Plus.v64'
"$2" = ''
"%k" = %k

Now First Try to run mupen64plus : without another script
 __  __                         __   _  _   ____  _             
|  \/  |_   _ _ __   ___ _ __  / /_ | || | |  _ \| |_   _ ___ 
| |\/| | | | | '_ \ / _ \ '_ \| '_ \| || |_| |_) | | | | / __|  
| |  | | |_| | |_) |  __/ | | | (_) |__   _|  __/| | |_| \__ \  
|_|  |_|\__,_| .__/ \___|_| |_|\___/   |_| |_|   |_|\__,_|___/  
             |_|         https://mupen64plus.org/               
Mupen64Plus Console User-Interface Version 2.5.9

UI-Console: attached to core library 'Mupen64Plus Core' version 2.5.9
UI-Console:             Includes support for Dynamic Recompiler.
Core: Using full mem base
Core: Goodname: Mupen64Plus Demo by Marshallh (GPL)
Core: Name: Mupen64Plus         
Core: MD5: DBF04773EC2B8ADF8A94DB7E3E461138
Core: CRC: DDBA4DE5 B107004A
Core: Imagetype: .v64 (byteswapped)
Core: Rom size: 1048576 bytes (or 1 Mb or 8 Megabits)
Core: Version: 1444
Core: Manufacturer: 0
Core: Country: Demo
UI-Console Status: Cheat codes disabled.
UI-Console: using Video plugin: 'Glide64mk2 Video Plugin' v2.5.9
UI-Console: using Audio plugin: 'Mupen64Plus SDL Audio Plugin' v2.5.9
Input: Using auto-config file at: './InputAutoCfg.ini'
Input: Using auto-config file at: './InputAutoCfg.ini'
UI-Console: using Input plugin: 'Mupen64Plus SDL Input Plugin' v2.5.9
UI-Console: using RSP plugin: 'Hacktarux/Azimer High-Level Emulation RSP Plugin' v2.5.9
Video: opening ./Glide64mk2.ini

Video: 3DNOW! detected.

Core: input plugin did not specify a render callback; there will be no on screen display by the input plugin.
Input: 2 SDL joysticks were found.
Input: N64 Controller #1: Using manual config with no SDL joystick (keyboard/mouse only)
Input: Using auto-config file at: './InputAutoCfg.ini'
Input: N64 Controller #2: Using auto-config with SDL joystick 0 ('Twin USB Joystick')
Input: Using auto-config file at: './InputAutoCfg.ini'
Input: N64 Controller #3: Using auto-config with SDL joystick 1 ('Twin USB Joystick')
Input: 3 controller(s) found, 3 plugged in and usable in the emulator
Input Warning: Couldn't open rumble support for joystick #1
Input: Rumble activated on N64 joystick #2
Input: Rumble activated on N64 joystick #3
Input Warning: Couldn't open rumble support for joystick #4
Input: Mupen64Plus SDL Input Plugin version 2.5.9 initialized.
RSP Error: Can't load library: mupen64plus-rsp-z64.so
Core: Using video capture backend: dummy
Core: Game controller 0 (Standard controller) has a Memory pak plugged in
Core: Game controller 1 (Standard controller) has a Memory pak plugged in
Core: Game controller 2 (Standard controller) has a Memory pak plugged in
Core: Game controller 3 (Standard controller) has a Memory pak plugged in
Core: Using CIC type X102
Video: Using TEXUMA extension.

&ConfigOpenSection is 0x7fcfd3f7e688
(II) Setting video mode 1058x885...
Core: Setting video mode: 1058x885
Congratulations, you have 4 auxilliary buffers, we'll use them wisely !
packed pixels extension used
NPOT extension used
use_fbo 1
Video: InitCombine() 
Video: extensions 
Video: initialized.
Video: 

Audio: Using resampler speex
Audio: Initializing SDL audio subsystem...
ALSA lib pcm_direct.c:1568:(_snd_pcm_direct_get_slave_ipc_offset) Invalid value for card
Input Warning: Couldn't open rumble support for joystick #1
Input: Rumble activated on N64 joystick #2
Input: Rumble activated on N64 joystick #3
Input Warning: Couldn't open rumble support for joystick #4
Core: Initializing 4 RDRAM modules for a total of 8 MB
Core: Starting R4300 emulator: Dynamic Recompiler
Core Status: Stopping emulation.
Core: R4300 emulator finished.
Core Status: Rom closed.
This work

Now Second Try to run mupen64plus : via another script
```

From script child

```
Autor ----------------> Inukaze ( Venezuela )
Sitio ----------------> https://goo.gl/ij6WqW
Correo-E -------------> bloginukaze@gmail.com
Licencia -------------> GPL 2

******* Inicio : Acerca de este Guión ********

  Yo intento escribir guiones compatibles con
   Sistemas operativos Unix & POSIX , y otros
   Sistemas operativos que soporten bash

  Este archivo es un guion sencillo para
  Iniciar "mupen64plus"
  [Emulador de Nintendo 64]

******** Fin : Acerca de este Guión **********


Antes del -z "$@" de 64 Bits
"$@" = ''
"$*" = ''
"$1" = ''
"$2" = ''
"%k" = '%k'
Despues del -z "$@" de 64 Bits
"$@" = ''
"$*" = ''
"$1" = ''
"$2" = ''
"%k" = '%k'
 __  __                         __   _  _   ____  _             
|  \/  |_   _ _ __   ___ _ __  / /_ | || | |  _ \| |_   _ ___ 
| |\/| | | | | '_ \ / _ \ '_ \| '_ \| || |_| |_) | | | | / __|  
| |  | | |_| | |_) |  __/ | | | (_) |__   _|  __/| | |_| \__ \  
|_|  |_|\__,_| .__/ \___|_| |_|\___/   |_| |_|   |_|\__,_|___/  
             |_|         https://mupen64plus.org/               
Mupen64Plus Console User-Interface Version 2.5.9

UI-Console: attached to core library 'Mupen64Plus Core' version 2.5.9
UI-Console:             Includes support for Dynamic Recompiler.
Core: Using full mem base
UI-Console Error: no ROM filepath given
```

From Parent Script

```
This not work

i need when mupen64plus script run for any folder store the absolute path of rom i want to run
For example : 

"/media/Compartido/Lignux/Videojuegos/Emulador/Nintendo/64/mupen64plus/portable/mupen64plus.geb" '/media/Nicolas/Temporal/ROMS/N64/Mupen64Plus.v64'

The first is absolute path my script
and the second is the absolute path of romfile
on another very diferent directory

i don't have idea how redirect absolute path of romfile from .desktop file
to bash variable before the mupen64plus execute
```

i need the child script use the romfile absolute path from parent script for launch mupen64plus with rom file correctly

and well if i ran using "Open with" from "Thunar" the output is the follow

```
First Argument is Empty Variable



i need when mupen64plus script run for any folder store the absolute path of rom i want to run
For example : 

"/media/Compartido/Lignux/Videojuegos/Emulador/Nintendo/64/mupen64plus/portable/mupen64plus.geb" '/media/Nicolas/Temporal/ROMS/N64/Mupen64Plus.v64'

The first is absolute path my script
and the second is the absolute path of romfile
on another very diferent directory

i don't have idea how redirect absolute path of romfile from .desktop file
to bash variable before the mupen64plus execute
```